# IE not passing over success function in AJAXFORM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajaxform, ie8-browser-mode

I have written this ajaxform function with a success function which is being called on sumiting the form. The ajaxform works AWESOMELY in any browser other than IE. I can´t understand why IE is not passing the function.

**AjaxForm:**

```
function setupAjaxForm(form_class, updateStatus){
            var form = '.'+form_class;
            var form_action = $(form).attr('action');
            var form_url = form_action+"ajax/";

            var submitOptions = {
                    url : form_url,
                    type : 'POST',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    success : function(json) {
                    var results = json.results;
                              alert(results);
                    if(results == "success"){
                        updateStatus(json);
                    }else{
                        alert(" FAIL ");
                                    }
                    }
            };
            $(form).ajaxForm(submitOptions);
        }
```

**Success function:**

```
function addProductCartStatus(json){
    alert(" Entered for jquery ");
}
```

**Calling function**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addto_cart').click(function(){new setupAjaxForm('add_cartForm',addProductCartStatus);});
});
```

Comment: There's no reason for `new` here, you're not invoking a constructor. Also, your code indentation is horrible, it took me 3 tries to figure out that the `}` after the alert matches the anonymous function...

Comment: It´s working in firefox and other browsers, It´s /NOT/ working in IE browsers. So, this mean that all the functions work. After which alert? If I am wrong please explain yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer goes mainly to your latest comment

internet explorer is more stiff in some cases. this line `result = "success"` as mentioned is wrong and converts result into a string with the word success in it and is always true so it always updates

also its recommended to add a `error:function(){}` on your ajax call

Comment: i hope if helped and always check with each browsers developer tools each variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(result = "success")
```

Should be

```
if(result == "success")
```

And you should use "{" for your if

```
if(result == "success") {
   updateStatus(json);
} else {
```

Comment: Actually it should be `===`, since no one should ever play the russian roulette of type coercion magic, yes it might be ok for string == string, but it's a matter of consistency :)

Comment: HAHAHA, let me try russian roulette :) but in IE, the alert(results) function is not even called.